# How can i replace all lines in a file with a pattern using Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a file with lines that i wish to remove like the following:

```
 key="Id" value=123"
 key="FirstName" value=Name1"
 key="LastName" value=Name2"
 <!--key="FirstName" value=Name3"
 key="LastName" value=Name4"-->
 key="Address" value=Address1"
 <!--key="Address" value=Address2"
 key="FirstName" value=Name1"
 key="LastName" value=Name2"-->
 key="ReferenceNo" value=765
```

have tried the following:            `

```
 $values = @('key="FirstName"','key="Lastname"', 'add key="Address"');
 $regexValues = [string]::Join('|',$values) 
 $lineprod = Get-Content "D:\test\testfile.txt" | Select-String $regexValues|Select-Object -          
    ExpandProperty Line    
 if ($null -ne $lineprod)
  {
   foreach ($value in $lineprod) 
    {    
    $prod = $value.Trim()
    $contentProd | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $prod,""} |Set-Content "D:\test\testfile.txt"
    }
 }
```

The issue is that only some of the lines get replaced and or removed and some remain.
The output should be

```
key="Id" value=123"
key="ReferenceNo" value=765
```

But i seem to get

```
key="Id" value=123"
key="ReferenceNo" value=765
<!--key="Address" value=Address2"
key="FirstName" value=Name1"
key="LastName" value=Name2"-->
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening or changes to the code above ?

Comment: I want to remove all lines that have the pattern key="FirstName"  , key="LastName" and  key="Address" the value may be different in each line

Comment: As an aside: consider using `$values -join '|'` instead of `[string]::Join('|', $values)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74541588/how-can-i-replace-all-lines-in-a-file-with-a-pattern-using-powershell?noredirect=1#comment131582846_74541588), the token `'add key="Address"'` should be changed for just `'key="Address"'` then the concatenating logic to build your regex looks good. You need to use the [`-NotMatch` switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.3#-notmatch) so it matches anything but those values. Also, `Select-String` can read files, so, `Get-Content` can be removed.

**Note**, the use of [`(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#grouping-operator--) in this case is important because you're reading and writing to the same file in the same pipeline. Wrapping the statement in parentheses ensure that all output from `Select-String` is consumed before passing it through the pipeline. Otherwise, you would end up with an empty file.

```bash
$values = 'key="FirstName"', 'key="Lastname"', 'key="Address"'
$regexValues = [string]::Join('|', $values)
(Select-String D:\test\testfile.txt -Pattern $regexValues -NotMatch) |
    ForEach-Object Line | Set-Content D:\test\testfile.txt
```

Outputs:

```
key="Id" value=123"
key="ReferenceNo" value=765
```